# Flash CS4 actionscript 2 - button controlling a movieclip within a movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript, cs4

I have a button directly on a stage. When this is clicked I want it to cause a movieclip INSIDE ANOTHER MOVIECLIP to move on one frame. When i use the

movieclip.gotoAndStop(2)

command, it wont work (If moviclip is the instance name of the movieclip I want to control)

I'm guessing its because the command would only work if the movieclip is on the stage with the button. Is there a different command i can use to pinpoint the movieclip when it is inside another one?

Thank you,
fred

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to reference the parent of movieclip (make sure the movieclip that contains 'movieclip' has an instance name):

```
movieclipParent.movieclip.gotoAndStop(2);
```